# On a thermostat, are "R" and "Rh" terminals the same thing?

Tags: hvac, thermostat

I have an older thermostat controlling an old ass Trane furnace with A/C. It has an "R" terminal and an "Rc" terminal (they are jumpered - see photo). I see references to an 
"Rh" terminal online. Are "R" and "Rh" terminals the same thing? This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8a_f2_iAW1U) refers to connecting the other external transformer wire to an "Rh" terminal and I am confused.

[image: Old Thermostat Terminals]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## R in general

`R`, `Rh`, and `Rc` are all the same, but not.  In general terms, the `R` terminal is where you connect the signal voltage source. In low voltage controlled systems, there will be a step down transformer that provides the power to the control circuitry.  One of the legs from the secondary of the transformer will be connected to the `R` terminal, which applies a voltage to the terminal.

When the thermostat wants to be warmed up or cooled down, it closes the appropriate switch, completing a circuit.  This allows current to flow from "into" the `R` terminal and "out of" the appropriate signal terminal (`W`, `Y`, etc.) of the thermostat.

## R, Rh, Rc

In some systems, both the heating and cooling systems use their own signal voltage. In these cases, the signal wire from the heating system will be connected to `R` or `Rh`, while the signal wire from the cooling system will be connected to `Rc`.

If only a single signal wire is used, the `R` terminal will be electrically connected (jumpered) to `Rh` and/or `Rc`.

[This answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/10527/33) has some diagrams that show how a simple single signal system works. [This answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/51650/33) provides another diagram of how a single signal thermostat works, though you can easily imagine how it could be modified to allow multiple signals.

A multiple signal system would look something like this...

[image: Multiple Signal HVAC System]
<sup>Click for larger view</sup>